# How to find the number of possible ways to climb the staircase

Tags: permutations, integer-programming, programming

> You are going to climb up a staircase that has an n number of stairs,
>   starting from bottom. In each step, you can only move up either one or
>   two stairs.
>
> Note that, as an example, after reaching the 3rd or 4th stairs, you
>   can climb up to the 5th stair in 2 ways;
>
> ```
>  I. move up 1 stair from the 4th stair, and
>
> II. move up 2 stairs from the 3rd stair.
> ```
>
> Develop a Python program to take an integer n as input (0 < n < 120)
>   and display the number of ways you can climb up to the nth stair. You
>   may handle unexpected inputs appropriately.
>
> Input: Single integer n (0
>
> Output: Single integer
>
> Example:
>
> Case 1:
>
> Input:
>
> 5 Output:
>
> 8 Case 2:
>
> Input:
>
> 9 Output:
>
> 55

Above is a question from one of my computer assignments. I don’t understand how to calculate the number of possible ways. To start coding I need a solution to the problem. How do I find the number of possible ways to climb the staircase.

Comment: This is just the sequence of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: The sequence goes $1,2,3,...$, the $n$th number is the $(n+1)$th Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say input$=1$, in this case output$=1$.

Now say input$=2$, in this case there is the answer of $($input$=1)$ and then another step and we have also the answer of taking $2$ steps(so $2$)

Now take input$=n$ in this case we have that output is: $($output$=n-1)$ with step of $1$ at the end and $($output$=n-2)$ with step of $2$ at the end

This is the same as the $n+1$ Fibonacci number

---

To make it clearer:

If I want to climb $10$ stairs. In this case I can climb $9$ and then climb a single stairs and I can also climb $8$ and then climb 2 stairs. So the number of ways to get to $10$ is the number of ways to get to $9$ plus the number of ways to get to $8$. And this is the same for all $n>2$.

Comment: Can you please explain further

Comment: @ulama if I have 10 stairs, I can go up $1$ stair and then I have $9$ stairs left. I can also go up $2$ stairs at the start, and then I have $8$ stairs left. So in the end I have the number of ways to go up $9$ stairs+the number of ways to go up $8$ stairs. And in general change $10$ into $n$, $9$ into $n-1$ and $8$ into $n-2$

Comment: I’m really sorry to keep bothering but I still don’t see the Fibonacci sequence

Comment: @ulama there is no problem. Do you understand why the number of ways to get to $10$ is the number of ways to get to $9$+ the number of ways to get to $8$?

Comment: Yeah, because the last step could be 1 step up or 2 steps up.

Comment: @ulama exactly. So the number of ways for $n$ stairs is the same as the number of ways for $n-1$ plus the number of ways for $n-2$?

Comment: Yes, I get that too. But how does it relate to the Febonacci sequence??

Comment: @ulama well, let's say $a_n=$ number of ways to get to the $n$th stair. From what I just showed we get that $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ right? Well this is exactly the general form of the Fibonacci sequence! The only thing left to do is to find $a_1,a_2$. I showed in my answer that they equal to $1,2$. The only difference from this to the Fibonacci sequence is that the Fibonacci sequence starts with $1,1$ and not $1,2$. Hence we just shift Fibonacci sequence and we get that $a_n=F_{n+1}$

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!